# Full-screen games on a Retina Macbook Pro sometimes start strangely

Tags: macbook-pro, games, resolution

When I start Braid on my Retina Macbook Pro, the game will sometimes start normally, and I can play it, but other times only the bottom left corner of the game is visible, and the graphics look really ugly. The same happens with Trine 2.

I don't know when it works or when it doesn't, just that it seems somewhat random to me. Could it have something to do with the graphics cards? Right now my battery is at 100%, and I'm connected to the charger, so I think the discrete card is the one powering the game. Could this be the problem? How do I tell?

Also, on each game's launcher, I select the "2880x1800" resolution.

Here's Braid looking all messed up:

[image: Less-than-impressive retina graphics]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @eternus for answering, but my issue was that for some reason, my computer doesn't always switch to the discrete card once I open a game. Restarting usually fixes the problem, but a more thorough way to solve it is to get this app called [gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io/), which allows you to specify which card you'd like to use. You choose the "Discrete only" option before running a game, and it should work fine. Here's what it looks like running in your task bar:

[image]

Comment: @nuc Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this with no extra apps by disabling "Automatic Graphics Switching" under the Energy Saver section of System Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the game isn't optimized for Retina Display, though it's odd that it sometimes works and sometimes not. Try setting the .app to open in Low Resolution. You can do this by right-clicking the .app file > Get Info and check "Low Resolution" option under the General section.

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer, but I figured out the problem (see below).

Comment: This didn't work for me since the Low Resolution option was already checked and greyed out.  Hassan's gfxCardStatus was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I could up vote @cidermonkey's answer, I would. You don't need an app (free or otherwise) to manually toggle the discreet graphics.

Comment: Consider posting a comment instead of an answer if you are not directly trying to answer what the question is about.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for that either. If/when I do, I'll circle back around and move this to a comment because you're right, it isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @cidermonkey's is not a bad answer (and I did upvote him/her), but I think disabling automatic graphics switching will kill your battery life. It's nice having the discrete card switch off when you're not using it.

Comment: Oh, for sure. I just turn automatic switching back on once I'm done playing.